# remove xs:annotation elements from schema

Tags: java, xml

I have a number of XSD schemas with too much documentation in them which makes them hard to read and use, how can I write a program to produce the equivalent XSD files with all the `xs:annotation` elements (including any `xs:appinfo`, `xs:documentation` or other elements they contain) removed whenever they may be found?

Answer (score 3):

You could run each of your files through an XSLT to strip out the unwanted elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="xs:annotation" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As noted by @IanRoberts You only really need to remove the `xs:annotation` elements and the other two types of elements will be removed along with them.

Comment: In fact just `<xsl:template match="xs:annotation"/>` would be enough as appinfo and documentation only occur inside annotation.